# How to download a file using WorkManager even when app is killed without having to restart service?

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

I am trying to download a file by using WorkManager when app is killed, it works completely fine when the app is in the foreground but when the app is killed the service(WorkManager) is restarted and the file starts downloading again.What I want to achieve is something similar to DownloadManagerApi but with custom notification like show progress and resume the download from the point where the app was killed and not restart the service. I have used WorkManager with OneTimeWorkRequest.

Comment: IMHO Workmanager doesn't suit this requirements. It's best suited for taks that can be deferred. Moreover the work is removed as soon as any criteria is not met and starts again once criteria is met. I would recommend using foreground services to achieve this

Comment: WorkManager does not support resume download. And you should not download file using WorkManager to download a file, because maximum processing time of a worker is 10 minutes, if you execute over 10 minutes, it will cause crash.

Comment: use `DownloadManager` - the docs say: *"he download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots"*

Comment: Use Foreground service to keep you application alive, even if you kill the app.
In onStartCommand, create you notification channel and notificaiton to show update to the user, then initiate your Download manager to download your data.

Comment: @Amit Kumar There are restrictions using Services in api 26 or higher. I want to achieve in all devices and the download should continue from the similar state even if app is killed

Comment: @pskink what if I want custom notification UI which is not possible to customise DownloadManager

Comment: yes it is: use `DownloadManager.query()` method to get current download data

Comment: @pskink I need to use **.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)** then by using DownloadManager.query() I will be able to calculate Total byte size and then update my custom notification via setProgress. But if user kills the app the how will that notification update the downloading bytes.am I correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct